# Custom Thread Pool - Reusing non-busy threads

Tags: java, multithreading, reinventing-the-wheel

This is an exercise in thread pooling in which I attempt (hopefully in a successful manner) to reuse existing threads (much like Java's own `ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool`). Essentially, my goal is: if all threads so far are busy doing their tasks, create a new thread in their place.

**MyCustomThreadPool.java**

```
package com.miguelmartins1987;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class MyCustomThreadPool {

    private List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
    private BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private boolean canAddTasks = true;

    public void shutdown() {
        canAddTasks = false;
        while (!taskQueue.isEmpty());
        for (Worker worker : workers) {
            worker.setRunning(false);
        }
    }

    public void submit(Runnable task) {
        if (canAddTasks) {
            taskQueue.add(task);
            Worker worker = getFreeWorker();
            if (worker == null) {
                System.out.println("No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: " + workers.size());
                worker = new Worker(workers.size() + 1);
                workers.add(worker);
                Thread thread = new Thread(worker);
                thread.start();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Reusing thread " + worker.getWorkerNumber());
            }
        }
    }

    private Worker getFreeWorker() {
        for (Worker worker : workers) {
            if (!worker.isBusy()) {
                return worker;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class Worker implements Runnable {

        private boolean busy = false;
        private boolean running = true;
        private int workerNumber;
        private int numberOfCompletedTasks = 0;

        public Worker(int workerNumber) {
            this.workerNumber = workerNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isRunning()) {
                Runnable task = taskQueue.poll();
                if (task != null) {
                    setBusy(true);
                    task.run();
                    ++numberOfCompletedTasks;
                    setBusy(false);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Worker " + workerNumber + " shutting down. It completed " + numberOfCompletedTasks + " tasks.");
        }

        public int getWorkerNumber() {
            return workerNumber;
        }

        public synchronized boolean isRunning() {
            return running;
        }

        public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

        public synchronized void setBusy(boolean busy) {
            this.busy = busy;
        }

        public synchronized boolean isBusy() {
            return busy;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.miguelmartins1987;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_TASKS = 50;
    protected static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCustomThreadPool cachedThreadPool = new MyCustomThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TASKS; ++i) {
            final int taskNumber = i + 1;
            Runnable task = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(RANDOM.nextInt(5000));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Task " + taskNumber + " complete.");
                }
            };
            cachedThreadPool.submit(task);
        }
        cachedThreadPool.shutdown();
    }

}
```

**Sample output**

```
run:
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 0
Reusing thread 1
Reusing thread 1
Reusing thread 1
Reusing thread 1
Reusing thread 1
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 1
Reusing thread 2
Reusing thread 2
Reusing thread 2
Reusing thread 2
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 2
Reusing thread 3
Reusing thread 3
Reusing thread 3
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 3
Reusing thread 4
Reusing thread 4
Reusing thread 4
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 4
Reusing thread 5
Reusing thread 5
Reusing thread 5
Reusing thread 5
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 5
Reusing thread 6
Reusing thread 6
Reusing thread 6
Reusing thread 6
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 6
Reusing thread 7
Reusing thread 7
Reusing thread 7
Reusing thread 7
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 7
Reusing thread 8
Reusing thread 8
Reusing thread 8
Reusing thread 8
Reusing thread 8
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 8
Reusing thread 9
Reusing thread 9
Reusing thread 9
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 9
Reusing thread 10
Reusing thread 10
Reusing thread 10
No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: 10
Reusing thread 11
Task 11 complete.
Task 10 complete.
Task 9 complete.
Task 3 complete.
Task 15 complete.
Task 4 complete.
Task 8 complete.
Task 13 complete.
Task 5 complete.
Task 6 complete.
Task 7 complete.
Task 20 complete.
Task 1 complete.
Task 17 complete.
Task 2 complete.
Task 12 complete.
Task 14 complete.
Task 25 complete.
Task 16 complete.
Task 18 complete.
Task 29 complete.
Task 32 complete.
Task 19 complete.
Task 27 complete.
Task 26 complete.
Task 28 complete.
Task 30 complete.
Task 23 complete.
Task 38 complete.
Task 35 complete.
Task 39 complete.
Task 34 complete.
Task 43 complete.
Task 24 complete.
Task 21 complete.
Task 22 complete.
Task 44 complete.
Task 45 complete.
Task 40 complete.
Task 33 complete.
Worker 4 shutting down. It completed 6 tasks.
Task 36 complete.
Worker 2 shutting down. It completed 3 tasks.
Task 31 complete.
Worker 8 shutting down. It completed 3 tasks.
Task 48 complete.
Worker 10 shutting down. It completed 7 tasks.
Task 37 complete.
Worker 9 shutting down. It completed 4 tasks.
Task 41 complete.
Worker 11 shutting down. It completed 5 tasks.
Task 50 complete.
Worker 3 shutting down. It completed 7 tasks.
Task 42 complete.
Worker 5 shutting down. It completed 5 tasks.
Task 46 complete.
Worker 6 shutting down. It completed 3 tasks.
Task 47 complete.
Worker 7 shutting down. It completed 3 tasks.
Task 49 complete.
Worker 1 shutting down. It completed 4 tasks.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 14 seconds)
```

Comment: What happens when I `submit(() -> while(true))` and then `shutdown`?

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. The program wouldn't terminate gracefully then. Perhaps I should consider adding an awaitTermination method, as well as a shutdownNow method...

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class MyCustomThreadPool {
```

In my opinion, `My...` names are useless, don't start with that practice. `CustomThreadPool` is an acceptable name enough for a test.

---

```java
while (!taskQueue.isEmpty());
```

You might want to choose a different form for waiting instead of a busy-loop. Having a `Thread.sleep` in there would already help, but even better would be to be notified every time a thread finishes its work.

---

```java
public void shutdown() {}
```

That method should most likely block until the last thread has exited.

---

```java
if (canAddTasks) {
```

This should either throw or return at least a `boolean` whether it was not possible to add a task.

---

```java
Worker worker = getFreeWorker();
if (worker == null) {
    System.out.println("No free worker available. Creating new thread... Current count: " + workers.size());
    worker = new Worker(workers.size() + 1);
    workers.add(worker);
    Thread thread = new Thread(worker);
    thread.start();
} else {
    System.out.println("Reusing thread " + worker.getWorkerNumber());
}
```

You have a slight race-condition there which you should be aware of. Between enqueuing the task and starting the new thread, another one might have finished and might already have grabbed the task. That is not a problem in itself, but you might spawn tasks unnecessarily.

---

```java
worker = new Worker(workers.size() + 1);
```

Your pool can only grow, it never shrinks.

---

```java
private Worker getFreeWorker() {
    for (Worker worker : workers) {
        if (!worker.isBusy()) {
            return worker;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

That is a race-condition right there. Again, not a problem in your implementation, but given the method you'd expect to get a `Worker` which is free, which might or might not be the case at the point when you receive the instance. It would be better to have a `boolean isFreeWorkerAvailable()` method which does only return `true` or `false`.

---

```java
while (isRunning()) {
    Runnable task = taskQueue.poll();
```

Again, you're busy waiting here. Blocking until something becomes available would be better. You want to use the `BlockingQueue.poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method, which allows you to wait some time (let's say 1 second) until something is available or not. That means that if no task is available, your thread will still check every second if it should exit.

---

```java
public synchronized void setBusy(boolean busy) {
```

This should not be a `public` method, anything external to the worker should not be able to set its state.

---

Comment: "You might want to choose a different form for waiting instead of a busy-loop." I would go as far as to say, please don't use a busy loop (or a sleep loop), it's a very bad habit to get into. Use a signal/condition variable/semaphore instead. I would block submission of this code into any professional code base during code review, simply based on the busy-loop alone.

Answer (score -2):

This Java program is well written but appreciate an Algorithm behind it.

When I see this it appears that workers take the task to process, but they 
need a thread and if we have method like a Factory method to assign a thread then that would look more cleaner. In this case we are checking if the worker is free and that use the thread of that worker can be checked inside the Factory method just like there is a Factory method for connection pools. The Flags for is busy and running can be made available to the Factory method as arguments.